# Compiling without using the host shared libraries

Tags: compiling

I am running on Archlinux.
My Qt project will be on a OpenSuse 15.1.

I have to compile it with the OpenSuse shared libraries from my Arch.

What is the best solution ?
Chroot? Virtual machine? Is it possible to specify others shared libs than host system to the linker ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH with:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/these/libraries:/path/to/those/libraries:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may need to set them for qmake itself:

```
export QMAKE_LIBDIR_FLAGS=-L/path/to/these/libraries:-L/path/to/those/libraries
```

You can also use the following for more options:

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake -help
```

Comment: But Qt Creator project doesn't use configure before build. I will try with QMAKE_LDFLAGS.

Comment: @rBeal I have update the answer as you are using `qmake`.